# ElasticSearch C# : after upgrade to Nest Version7.0, Invalid NEST response built from a successful (404) low level call on HEAD

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have upgraded my Nest to a newer version 7.X on my C# dotnetCore project.

Now all my code has changed to respect the No type rule implemented in the new version BUT..
in some methodes (Like :

```
 ElasticClient.DocumentExistsAsync<T>(id)
```

)
, I'm no longer able to get the response from ElasticSearch, instead I get :
Invalid NEST response built from a successful (404) low level call on HEAD
and when checking on the logs I see that the request is created this way :

```
IndexName/_doc/id
```

when checking on Kibana this request is not valid instead I have to change it to
`IndexName/myType/id` so that it can works

Now, I don't know how to make my ElasticClient create the same request, or get the response I'm waiting for.
Ill appreciate any help, thank you

Comment: What version of Elasticsearch are you using NEST 7.x with?

Comment: it's 7.13 @RussCam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION : For the record and FYI. it's not possible to use the native NEST methodes (GET, Exist, ExistDoc ...) from a nest library Version 7.X when the Elastic search you have in your server has a version 6.X
Why is that ?
Because after the version 7 Elastic search eliminated the Types. so when you create a request from a (6.x) library it take in consideration the Type associated with the request, it becomes something like `IndexName/myType/id`
but in the ESv7.x there is no `myType` in the request instead you will always find `_doc` like : `IndexName/_doc/id` which doesn't represent the Type but only the routing to the doc.
So conclusion :
If you upgrade your ES server => upgrade your libraries
If you upgrade your library and you don't have problem with upgrading the ES server => upgrade the ES server
If you have issues, you can still upgrade the library but don't use the native methode, instead use `.Search<>`